# Get observable value in my component variable - Angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Using Angular 13, I have the following observable in my service:

```js
      private _user = new BehaviorSubject<ApplicationUser | null>(null); 
      user$ = this._user.asObservable();
```

The ApplicationUser model is as follow:

```js
    export interface ApplicationUser {
      userName: string;
      role: string;
    }
```

I know how to access user$ from the template like:

```html
    <li *ngIf="authService.user$ | async as user ; else login">
                  <a href="#" data-uk-icon="user">{{ user.userName }}</a>              
                </li>
```

But I would like to manipulate it in my component.
I have tried:

```js
    user!: ApplicationUser;
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
    
        this.authService.user$      
          .subscribe((test: ApplicationUser) => {
            this.user = test; 
          });
    }
```

Also tried

```js
    this.user=this.authService.user$.subscribe();
```

But it complains that Subscription is missing the following properties (username, role)

Also tried

```js
    this.authService.user$
          .subscribe(test=> this.user = test);
```

But it complains that Type 'ApplicationUser | null' is not assignable to type 'ApplicationUser'

What should be the correct syntax in my component to get the observable into my user variable?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "manipulate"? Normally you will proceed using rxjs operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `!` to the subscription emitted value:

```js
this.authService.user$.subscribe((test) => this.user = test!);
```

Comment: It gives me the following error:  `Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(test: ApplicationUser) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: ApplicationUser | null) => void'. `

Comment: Sorry, I oversaw that you specified type of the `test`. I updated my answer. Can you tried it again?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @NeNad. Got the syntax now.